# data.EventCallback was null

Tags: c#

I'm trying to set GLFW.NET to log some input callbacks. However, i'm unable due to an error when trying to get register those actions on my Event script.

The error is the following:

System.NullReferenceException HResult=0x80004003 Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Source=Jade StackTrace: at Jade.WindowsWindow.b__9_5(IntPtr window, Double xPos, Double yPos) in D:\Projects\Camellia Engine\Jade\Exclusive\Windows\WindowsWindow.cs:line 163

**It occurs everytime I use my "data.EventCallback()" function.**

**Here's my code:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using GLFW;
using GLFW.Game;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Jade
{
    internal class WindowsWindow : Window
    {
        public static bool m_isGLFWInitialized = false;
        public WindowsWindow(WindowProps props) {
            Init();
        }
        ~WindowsWindow()
        {
            Shutdown();
        }

        public override void OnUpdate()
        {
            Glfw.PollEvents();
            Glfw.SwapBuffers(m_window);
        }

        public override uint GetWidth()
        {
            return (uint)m_Data.Width;
        }

        public override uint GetHeight()
        {
            return (uint)m_Data.Height;
        }

        public override void SetEventCallback(in EventCallbackFn callback)
        {
            m_Data.EventCallback = callback;
        }

        public override void SetVSync(bool enabled)
        {
            if (enabled)
            {
                 Glfw.SwapInterval(1);
            } else
            {
                Glfw.SwapInterval(0);
            }

            m_Data.VSync = enabled;
        }

        public override bool IsVSyncEnabled()
        {
            return m_Data.VSync;
        }

        public void Init()
        {
            WindowProps props = new WindowProps();
            m_Data.Title = props.Title;
            m_Data.Width = props.Width;
            m_Data.Height = props.Height;

            Log.CM_CORE_INFO("Creating window named " + props.Title + " and with paremeters " + props.Width + "x" + props.Height);

            if (!m_isGLFWInitialized)
            {
                bool success = Glfw.Init();
                Log.CM_CORE_ASSERT(success, "GLFW couldn't be initialized");
                Glfw.SetErrorCallback(GlfwErrorCallback);
                m_isGLFWInitialized = true;
            }
            m_window = new NativeWindow((int)props.Width, (int)props.Height, m_Data.Title, GLFW.Monitor.None, GLFW.Window.None);
            IntPtr dataPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(m_Data));
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(m_Data, dataPtr, false);
            SetVSync(true);
            Glfw.MakeContextCurrent(m_window);
            Glfw.SetWindowUserPointer(m_window, dataPtr);
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(dataPtr);

            #region GLFW Callbacks
            //Set GLFW Callbacks
                Glfw.SetWindowSizeCallback(m_window, (window, width, height) =>
                    {
                        WindowData data = Marshal.PtrToStructure<WindowData>(Glfw.GetWindowUserPointer(m_window));

                        WindowResizeEvent m_event = new WindowResizeEvent((uint)width, (uint)height);

                        data.Width = (uint)width;
                        data.Height = (uint)height;

                        data.EventCallback(m_event);
                    });

                Glfw.SetCloseCallback(m_window, (window) =>
                {
                    WindowData data = Marshal.PtrToStructure<WindowData>(Glfw.GetWindowUserPointer(m_window));

                    WindowCloseEvent m_event = new WindowCloseEvent();

                    data.EventCallback(m_event);
                });

                Glfw.SetKeyCallback(m_window, (window, key, scancode, action, mod) =>
                {
                    WindowData data = Marshal.PtrToStructure<WindowData>(Glfw.GetWindowUserPointer(m_window));
                    KeyCode keyCode = (KeyCode)key;

                    switch (action)
                    {
                        case InputState.Press:
                            KeyPressedEvent m_pressEvent = new KeyPressedEvent(keyCode, false);
                            data.EventCallback(m_pressEvent);
                            break;

                        case InputState.Release:
                            KeyReleasedEvent m_releaseEvent = new KeyReleasedEvent(keyCode);
                            data.EventCallback(m_releaseEvent);
                            break;

                        case InputState.Repeat:
                            KeyPressedEvent m_repeatEvent = new KeyPressedEvent(keyCode, true);
                            data.EventCallback(m_repeatEvent);
                            break;
                    }
                });

                Glfw.SetMouseButtonCallback(m_window, (window, button, action, mods) =>
                {
                    MouseCode mouseCode = (MouseCode)button;
                    WindowData data = Marshal.PtrToStructure<WindowData>(Glfw.GetWindowUserPointer(m_window));

                    switch (action)
                    {
                        case InputState.Press:
                            MouseButtonPressedEvent m_pressEvent = new MouseButtonPressedEvent(mouseCode);
                            data.EventCallback(m_pressEvent);
                            break;

                        case InputState.Release:
                            MouseButtonReleasedEvent m_releaseEvent = new MouseButtonReleasedEvent(mouseCode);
                            data.EventCallback(m_releaseEvent);
                            break;
                    }
                });

                Glfw.SetScrollCallback(m_window, (window, xOffset, yOffset) =>
                {
                    WindowData data = Marshal.PtrToStructure<WindowData>(Glfw.GetWindowUserPointer(m_window));
                    MouseScrolledEvent m_scrollEvent = new MouseScrolledEvent((float)xOffset, (float)yOffset);
                    data.EventCallback(m_scrollEvent);
                });

                Glfw.SetCursorPositionCallback(m_window, (window, xPos, yPos) =>
                {
                    WindowData data = Marshal.PtrToStructure<WindowData>(Glfw.GetWindowUserPointer(m_window));
                    MouseMovedEvent m_moveEvent = new MouseMovedEvent((float)xPos, (float)yPos);
                    data.EventCallback(m_moveEvent);
                });

            #endregion
        }

        private void GlfwErrorCallback(ErrorCode error, nint errorDescription)
        {
            Log.CM_CORE_ERROR("GLFW Error!: " + error + ": " + errorDescription);
        }

        private GLFW.Window m_window;

        public override Window Create(WindowProps props = default)
        {
            return new WindowsWindow(props);
        }

        public void Shutdown() 
        {
            Glfw.DestroyWindow(m_window);
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct WindowData
        {
            public string Title;
            public uint Width, Height;
            public bool VSync;

            public EventCallbackFn EventCallback;
        };


        WindowData m_Data;


    }
}
```

I expected to receive some logs into the console such as: [DATE]|INFO|Camellia Engine| [Event Type and details"]
I tried to use the nint (window) but received error CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'nint' to 'GLFW.Window'

Comment: No. I already know what it is. I'm trying to understand and solve WHY I am getting that error considering it's the ONLY variable that's null

Comment: Well, your `data` variable is null because whatever does `Marshal.PtrToStructure<WindowData>(Glfw.GetWindowUserPointer(m_window));` returns, in that specific moment, `null`.

Comment: Do note that linking to code repositories is not a good way to ask a question because questions should have in them enough information to be able to be reproduced and links can die/be broken.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing with that `Marshal.PtrToStructure` is incredibly bad, partly because you don't seem to understand how it works, and partly because the pattern is just plain bad. Are you doing it because you don't know how to call variables?

I'll fix one of the event handlers for you, apply a similar fix to the rest of them:

```
            Glfw.SetCloseCallback(m_window, window =>
                m_data.EventCallback?.Invoke(new WindowCloseEvent()));
```